# tensorboard execution from google cloud machine

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, tensorboard, google-cloud-datalab

I am new to tensorboard and trying to make it work on my GCE that runs google cloud datalab.

I am using the code from:
https://github.com/MorvanZhou/tutorials/blob/master/tensorflowTUT/tf15_tensorboard/full_code.py

the data is saved on logs folder on the GCE. therefore the execution command from the datalab is:
!tensorboard --logdir="./logs"

i tried opening network port and then using the external IP address with the port (could not reach the graph)
gcloud beta compute firewall-rules create tensorboard --action allow  --rules tcp:6006 --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0

running the same thing on my local machine, worked fine. I am using large dataset with big computing and can not work locally.

any idea?

Many thanks,
Eila

Comment: Possible duplicate of [launching tensorboard from google cloud datalab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046819/launching-tensorboard-from-google-cloud-datalab)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried with port forwarding with no success: Hello,

Help pleasssse

**I tried this solution for local machine (MAC):**
on the local machine, i run:
gcloud auth login

**on the console:**
gcloud compute firewall-rules create tensorboard-port --allow tcp:6006

**On the Mac, port forward configutaion:**
gcloud compute ssh datalabvm-pgp --project project_id --zone  us-east1-b --ssh-flag="-R" --ssh-flag="6006:localhost:6006"

on the datalab machine:
!tensorboard --logdir="./logs" --debug

**on the local machine (MAC)**
http://35.190.179.233:6006

**the result:**
This site can’t be reached

35.190.179.233 took too long to respond.
Search Google for 190 179 233 6006
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

what am i missing?

Many thanks!!